# htaccess RewriteRule confusion

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am experiencing a minor difficulty. I have a webpage, and have created a CMS for maintaining the content.

Every time a site is created in the admin part of the system, i have done it so that the .htaccess file is updated.

I only use the .htaccess file to create user friendly URL's.

My .htaccess file looks something like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule home.html index.php?page_id=2
RewriteRule producenter.html index.php?page_id=13
RewriteRule produkter.html index.php?page_id=12
RewriteRule om-oss.html index.php?page_id=14
RewriteRule producent-3-s.html index.php?show_manu=true&manu_id=4
RewriteRule bildbank-producent-3-s.html index.php?show_manu_press=true&manu_id=4
...
```

Everything works fine, with a small exception.
If the names are "similar", as in in the case:

```
  producent-3-s.html
  and
  bildbank-producent-3-s.html
```

The site will automatically show the first occurance, e.g. 'producent-3-s.html'.
So 'bildbank-producent-3-s.html' will never be shown.

How can i fix this? I hope i made my self clear, and thanks in advance for any help and tips i might get

Comment: Just add: `^producent-3-s.html$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way write `RewriteRule producent-3-s.html ...` after `RewriteRule bildbank-producent-3-s.html ...` rule

Comment: hmmm.. then it will not be possible to reach      'producent-3-s.html', so it's not really a solution :(

Comment: well this actually worked. Thank you very much :)
What happend here?
I would like to know, so that i can prevent the problem in the future. Since the user can create multiple pages, i can't really controle how the htaccess file will look like.

Comment: i will accept the answer, how? this is my very first post here :)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder the rules in the htaccess so that the more specific ones come first.
If you don't like that, try slashes.